# In nodejs How can I add an object containing functions to a class object so I can get something like class.object.function(args)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to make something like

```
class ClassObj{
constructor(){}
create = {person:function(args)}
}
```

So when using the class instance I can

```
const c = new ClassObj
c.create.person(args)
```

I attempted to

```
Object.defineProperty(ClassObj, 'create', {
    person: function(name){return name}
  });
```

however the error c.create.person is not a function occurs

I've also tried

```
class ClassObj{
   constructor() {
   this.create = {person:function(name){console.log(name)}
   }
}
```

which caused the function to run when the class was instanced which is not a desired behavior for me and didn't give a way to really pass arguments easily into the function.  any help would be appreciated

Comment: Should it be part of the members or of the constructor? your statements are contradicting...

Comment: Note that you are missing an enclosing `}`

Comment: @JonasW. I'd prefer it to be part of the members and just be able to access with classobj.obj.function(args)

Comment: then your slast snippet will work (if you remove the typo)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this (your constructors will assign the attributes to your class):

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.person = null
    this.create = (args) => {
      this.person = new Person(args)
    }
  }
}

class Person {
  constructor(person) {
    this.name = person.name
    this.age = person.age
  }
}

let a = new A()
a.create({name: "Peter", age: "24"})
console.log(a)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes